# CSS Selectors - How to apply a defined class on the selector's event

Tags: html, css, events, selector

How can I apply a class properties to a class which has selectors in pure CSS? Example:

```
.one{color:red;}

.two{color:blue;}
.two:hover{ /*Apply class ".one" to class ".two" when the event is triggered */}
```

Comment: CSS doesn't have inheritance. To achieve this you have to use a CSS preprocessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quite simple:

```
.two {
    color: blue;
}
.one, .two:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Hope this helps!
If you ever did port over to SASS you could do it a little cleaner like:

```
.one {
    color: blue;
}
.two {
    color: red;
    &:hover {
        @extend .one;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comma separated classes sharing properties would do the job. Thanks!